# Upload files from (Fast)API to Azure Blob Storage

Tags: reactjs, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-blob-storage, fastapi

I'm trying to create a function that let me select a file from input on the frontend, then pass the file to the backend FastAPI, and eventually upload the file to Azure Blob storage. My Frontend code is below:

```
//front end
async function handleSubmit(){
    
    const formdata = new FormData();
    formdata.append(
      "file",
      file[0],
    )

    const headers={'Content-Type': file[0].type}

    await axios.post("/uploadfile",formdata,headers)
    .then(function (response) {
      console.log(response)
          });
  }
```

Backend FastAPI - two methods I tried

```
//Backend FastAPI
@app.post("/uploadfile") //currently using 
async def create_upload_file(file: UploadFile):
    name = file.filename
    type = file.content_type
    return uploadtoazure(file,name,type)

@app.post("/files") //another method I tried
async def create_file(file: bytes= File()):
    
    await uploadtoazure(file)
```

And the uploadtoazure() function

```
//Backend uploadtoazure() function
async def uploadtoazure(f,n,t):
    connect_str = ""//removed from sample code
   
    blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(connect_str)
    container_name = "notes"

    file = f.read()
    local_file_name = n
    cnt_settings = ContentSettings(content_type=t)

    blob_client = blob_service_client.get_blob_client(container=container_name, blob=local_file_name)
    
    blob_client.upload_blob(file,cnt_settings)
```

The error kept coming at me and when I tried another method another new error prevents me from moving forward.

Some problem I'm aware:

- `blob_client.upload_blob()` only accept some types of files, in which the file type I passed in from API isn't one of it.
- I used the sample code in https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/request-files/In which I am not quite sure of the characteristic of the class `UploadFile` and `File()`.
- When I use the method which the file passed to API is `file: bytes= File()`, the file type seems able to upload to the blob storage, however it does not have a content type or suffix, hence I think finding a way to pass in the content_type of the file could be another solution, but it was harder than I thought.

I hope there's enough information, I desperately need someone to clear my confusion. Thank you very much.

Comment: The type of files is managed in the storage account. Default settings should be broad enough for many file-types. What kind of files do you use? We use FastAPI for uploading images to Azure Blob Storage and that works perfectly. Can you share the errors you face?

Comment: Hi: I think the problem is how I handle the UploadFile type parameter, and how I treat the async and await in the function that causes the problem. The errors I received include ```TypeError: Unsupported data type: <class 'coroutine'>```  and ```ValueError: [TypeError("'coroutine' object is not iterable"), TypeError('vars() argument must have __dict__ attribute')]``` . And I think it is all associated with the uploadtoazure() function during handling of the file passed in from API, specifically when doing ```upload_blob```. If you do know why the error occur it would be a great help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were pretty close, but there are some improvements. For example, you are using synchronous and asynchronous code together. This leads to confusing issues, such as not awaiting `f.read()` while that is an async method. Also, you don't have to pass content type to the azure storage blob client, just leave that to Azure.

I would recommend to use the async version of the azure-storage-blob package.

I re-wrote it a little. The below will run as-is and is a full working example.

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, HTTPException, UploadFile
from azure.storage.blob.aio import BlobServiceClient

app = FastAPI()

@app.post("/uploadfile")
async def create_upload_file(file: UploadFile):
    name = file.filename
    type = file.content_type
    return await uploadtoazure(file,name,type)


async def uploadtoazure(file: UploadFile,file_name: str,file_type:str):
    connect_str = "HERE_YUOUR_CONNECTION_STRING"
    blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(connect_str)
    container_name = "stackoverflow"
    async with blob_service_client:
            container_client = blob_service_client.get_container_client(container_name)
            try:
                blob_client = container_client.get_blob_client(file_name)
                f = await file.read()
                await blob_client.upload_blob(f)
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)
                return HTTPException(401, "Something went terribly wrong..")
    
    return "{'did_it_work':'yeah it did!'}"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import uvicorn
    uvicorn.run(app, host="0.0.0.0", port=8000, )
```

Hope this clarifies some bits!

Comment: Thank you so much. I have one additional question, what's the difference between importing ```BlobServiceClient``` from ```azure.storage.blob.aio``` and ```azure.storage.blob```, as I think the code works for the "aio" version. Also, sometimes the Axios post returns ```AxiosError {message: 'Network Error', name: 'AxiosError', code: 'ERR_NETWORK'```. I have set the proxy to ```"proxy": "http://localhost:8000/"``` in package.json, but sometimes, the previous post works, and the next post, it returns error. If you need any extra information, I would be glad to follow up.

Comment: **Update**: I have fixed the AxiosError problem, and I think the ```azure.storage.blob.aio``` is the async version of ```azure.storage.blob```? When I used the "non async version" and does ```f = await file.read()```, I remember when uploading it returns error like ```TypeError: Unsupported data type: <class 'coroutine'>``` and ```ValueError: [TypeError("'coroutine' object is not iterable")```. Does the async version is the key to solve this problem? And what is the role of ```async with``` plays in the code?

Comment: `azure.storage.blob.aio` is indeed the async version of the the BlobServiceClient, allowing blocking calls to be awaited. An async function (e.g. a method defined with `async def` doesn't actually return the return object, but a `coroutine` object when called. Only when it is awaited, it will execute the code in the async method and return the actual return object. I found a fantastic tutorial on async, which will explain it in better detail and I highly recommend you give it a good read: https://bbc.github.io/cloudfit-public-docs/